# Space efficient C++ vector allocator for large vectors?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdvector

I'm working with some C++ code that implements a graph algorithm that uses a lot of small chunks of memory (a relative of gSpan, but that doesn't matter).  The code is implemented in C++ and uses std::vectors to store many small elements (on the order of 64 bytes each).  However, I'm using this on much larger data sets than the original authors, and I'm running out of memory.

It appears, however, that I'm running out of memory prematurely. Fragmentation? I suspect it is because std::vectors are trying to increase in size every time they need more memory, and vectors insist on contiguous memory.  I have 8GB of ram and 18GB of swap, yet when std::bad_alloc is thrown, I'm only using 6.5GB resident and ~8GB virtual. I've caught the bad_alloc calls and printed out the vector sizes and here's what I see:

```
size: 536870912
capacity: 536870912
maxsize: 1152921504606846975
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
    what():  std::bad_alloc
```

So, clearly, we've hit the maximum size of the vector and the library is trying to allocate more, and failing.

So my questions are:

- Am I correct in assuming that is what the problem is?
- What is the solution (besides "buy more RAM").  I'm willing to trade CPU time for fitting in memory.
- Should i convert the entire code to use std::list (and somehow implement operator[] for the places the code uses it?).. would that even be more ram efficient? at the very least it would allow the list elements to be non-contiguous...right?
- Is there a better allocator out there that I can use to override the standard on for vectors for this use case?
- What other solutions am I missing?

Since I don't know how much memory will ultimately used, I'm aware that even if I make changes there still might not be enough memory to do my calculations, but I suspect I can get at least a lot further then I'm getting now, which seems to be giving up very quickly.

Comment: I should clarify, the bad_alloc is thrown as a new element is attempted to be added with push_back().

Comment: If the algorithm requires random access (as opposed to just sequential), then replacing the vectors with linked lists is guaranteed to give *awful* performance. Getting the nth element of a M-element linked list requires dereferencing a pointer `min{n, M - n}` times. For in your case, a single call to `operator[]` would require hundred, perhaps many thousands, in some cases even millions of instructions (each of which is relatively slow on its own). With such large data sets, that's practically guaranteed to make your program take forever.

Comment: If the vector needs to grow, it *temporarily* requires about twice as much RAM as a vector is always stored in a continuous block of memory. If it grows, it allocates a larger one, moves all elements and only then frees the previous one. Is it possible for you to know the upper limit of elements? If so, try using [`reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) on the vector at the beginning.

Comment: Concerning heap fragmentation, take a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15720503/420683)

Comment: @delnan I'm very aware it (could be) many orders of magnitude slower to use a list.  However, it might actually be able to finish, rather then bailing out after only using about half the available memory.

Comment: What platform? OS? --depending on how you build your program you might be limited to something much smaller than 8+18Gb.

Comment: @dribeas Linux amd64.

Comment: @clemej Finishing but taking a million times longer does not sound very convincing. Even if the program would take only a second with vectors (you can hardly *touch* so much memory in a second with today's RAM) the million-times-slower program takes 11 days. With a more realistic 1 minute * 10,000 it's almost 7 days. All assuming the time is dominated by lookups, but I assume it's at least a large enough fraction to still put the actual time in the days range. Aside from that, a linked list would also at significantly grow memory requirements, if applied naively (one list node/64 byte item).

Comment: @delnan You are correct and I fully understand all that.. and I'm also willing to let something run for a few days/weeks if necessary.  I'm much more concerned with feasibility than speed at this point.  If I can prove it can be done, THEN I'll worry about speed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try using `std::deque` as a direct drop-in for `vector`. There's a possibility that since it (often) uses a collection of chunks, extending the `deque` could be much cheaper than extending a `vector` (in terms of extra memory needed).

Comment: (reads up on deque) Seems close to what I'm looking for! I'll try it and see.  May not solve the issue but may get a lot closer.

Comment: Cool. deque's didn't make the program work but at least gave me semi-predictable behavior and used a lot more memory before running out.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Double-plus bonus points for it being a simple "sed -i 's/vector/deque/g'".

Comment: Deque also doesn't appear to be significantly slower than vectors in this use case.